# PHP header() does not redirect with status code

Tags: php, redirect, header

I have a code

```
<?php
header('Location: http://mydomain/404', true, 404);
exit;
?>
```

which does nothing. Outputs with a white screen and I can watch 404 response status, but no redirect.
Ubuntu 12.04 / PHP 5.3

Same problem on server with Debian Squeeze / PHP 5.3

What I do wrong?

Update.

It is a part of function that takes status and path.
I need a redirect to a specified page with a specified status code.
Not direct display 404 page.

Comment: Does this url exist for your domain `http://mydomain/404`

Comment: Sure, it is a page handled by Apache Rewrite.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't have a Location redirect for a 404. The correct behavior would be to include the 404 page in the result with a 404 header.

```
<?
header( $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']." 404 Not Found", true, 404 );
include('404.php');
?>
```

That is unless the 404 page is on another domain. In which case you can simply use a Location redirect without the 404 like Apache does by default when it can't find your error document.

Comment: Seems that I understood problem.

Answer (score 4):

It's either a 404 Not Found or a 302 Redirect, it can't be both at the same time. If you want to signal *This Page Does Not Exist*, use a 404. If you want to redirect the user, use a 302.

Comment: You mean I can not do redirect using Location header with status != 301/302?

Comment: Exactly! The status codes have a specific meaning for what the client should do. 3xx codes are redirects, 4xx codes are errors.

Answer (score 0):

Do this via .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
</IfModule>
```